# JavaScript var object perfom function on attribute

Tags: javascript, html, slice

So, I'm trying to modify an already existing html file (uses embedded javascript) and change the way it outputs table data. The data that is being inputted into the table is being pulled from another program which stores this one value I want to change as a decimal value. Scouring through the code, I found the section that actually handles what data will be displayed to the table, and it as follows.

```
var bodyDefine =
        [
            //{ text: rankingText, width: "5%", align: "center", effect: deadYatsuEffect },
            { text: "{name}", width: "10%" },
            { text: "{Job}", width: "8%", align: "left" },
            { text: "{encdps}", width: "20%", align: "right" },
            //{ text: "{damage%}", width: "5%", align: "right" },
            //{ text: "{enchps}", width: "16%", align: "right" },
            //{ text: "{healed%}", width: "5%", align: "right" },
            //{ text: "{tohit}%", width: "16%", align: "right" },
            //{ text: "{crithit%}", width: "14%", align: "right" },
        ];
```

Edit:
The current output is as follows(example):

```
    Name     Job      DPS
|John Smith  NIN   12653.25  |
|Adam Cook   SAM   14577.32  |
```

But the intended output I want is without the decimal values under DPS.

```
    Name     Job      DPS
|John Smith  NIN   12653  |
|Adam Cook   SAM   14577  |
```

**This file was retrieved from https://github.com/hibiyasleep/OverlayPlugin/releases/tag/0.3.4.0 and is used with the program Advanced Combat Tracker with the FFXIV_ACT Plugin. The file below is located in the following directory OverlayPlugin-0.3.4.0-x64-full/resources/miniparse.html**

The entire code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <!--STYLE SECTION REMOVED-->
    <script>

        //
        // プラグイン側から以下のような ActXiv オブジェクトとしてデータが提供される
        //
        // var ActXiv = {
        //    "Encounter": {...},
        //    "Combatant": {
        //        "PlayerName1": {...},
        //        "PlayerName2": {...},
        //        ...
        //    }
        // };
        //
        // データの更新は 1 秒毎。
        // 
        // プラグインから onOverlayDataUpdate イベントが発行されるので、それを受信することもできる
        // イベントハンドラの第一引数の detail プロパティ内に上記のオブジェクトが入る
        //

        //
        // 表示設定 (2)
        //

        // エンカウント情報の定義
        var encounterDefine = "{title} / Time: {duration} / DPS: {ENCDPS}";

        // 上記のエンカウント情報を HTML として扱うなら true
        var useHTMLEncounterDefine = false;

        // ヘッダの定義
        var headerDefine =
        [
            //{ text: "#", width: "5%", align: "center" },
            { text: "Name", width: "10%", align: "left" },
            { text: "Job", width: "8%", align: "left" },
            { text: "DPS", width: "20%", align: "right"},
            //{ text: "HPS (%)", width: "18%", align: "center", span: 2 },
            //{ text: "Acc.(%)", width: "16%", align: "right" },
            //{ text: "Crt.(%)", width: "14%", align: "right" },
        ];

        // 表示するデータの定義
        var bodyDefine =
        [
            //{ text: rankingText, width: "5%", align: "center", effect: deadYatsuEffect },
            { text: "{name}", width: "10%" },
            { text: "{Job}", width: "8%", align: "left" },
            { text: "{encdps}", width: "20%", align: "right" },
            //{ text: "{damage%}", width: "5%", align: "right" },
            //{ text: "{enchps}", width: "16%", align: "right" },
            //{ text: "{healed%}", width: "5%", align: "right" },
            //{ text: "{tohit}%", width: "16%", align: "right" },
            //{ text: "{crithit%}", width: "14%", align: "right" },
        ];

        // 順位を表示する（text に関数を指定する例）
        // 引数:
        //  combatant : キャラクターのデータ。combatant["..."]でデータを取得できる。
        //  index : キャラクターの並び順。一番上は 0 で、その後は 1 ずつ増える。
        // 戻り値: 
        //  表示するテキスト。
        //  ACT のタグは展開されないので、展開したい場合は parseActFormat 関数を使用してください。
        function rankingText(combatant, index) {
            // 1 から始まる番号を返す
            return (index + 1).toString();
        }

        // 死亡奴を赤くする（effect の例）
        // 引数:
        //  cell : セルの DOM 要素
        //  combatant : キャラクターのデータ。combatant["..."]でデータを取得できる。
        //  index: キャラクターの並び順。一番上は 0 で、その後は 1 ずつ増える。
        // 戻り値: なし
        function deadYatsuEffect(cell, combatant, index) {
            // デス数を整数値に変換
            var deaths = parseInt(combatant["deaths"]);
            // デス数が 0 よりも大きいなら
            if (deaths > 0) {
                // 赤くする
                cell.style.color = "#FFA0A0";
                cell.style.textShadow = "-1px 0 3px #802020, 0 1px 3px #802020, 1px 0 3px #802020, 0 -1px 3px #802020";
            }
        }

        //
        // 以下表示用スクリプト
        //

        // onOverlayStateUpdate イベントを購読
        document.addEventListener("onOverlayStateUpdate", function (e) {
            if (!e.detail.isLocked) {
                displayResizeHandle();
            } else {
                hideResizeHandle();
            }
        });

        function displayResizeHandle() {
            document.documentElement.classList.add("resizeHandle");
        }

        function hideResizeHandle() {
            document.documentElement.classList.remove("resizeHandle");
        }

        // onOverlayDataUpdate イベントを購読
        document.addEventListener("onOverlayDataUpdate", function (e) {
            update(e.detail);
        });

        // 表示要素の更新
        function update(data) {
            updateEncounter(data);
            if (document.getElementById("combatantTableHeader") == null) {
                updateCombatantListHeader();
            }
            updateCombatantList(data);
        }

        // エンカウント情報を更新する
        function updateEncounter(data) {
            // 要素取得
            var encounterElem = document.getElementById('encounter');

            // テキスト取得
            var elementText;
            if (typeof encounterDefine === 'function') {
                elementText = encounterDefine(data.Encounter);
                if (typeof elementText !== 'string') {
                    console.log("updateEncounter: 'encounterDefine' is declared as function but not returns a value as string.");
                    return;
                }
            } else if (typeof encounterDefine === 'string') {
                elementText = parseActFormat(encounterDefine, data.Encounter);
            } else {
                console.log("updateEncounter: 'encounterDefine' should be string or function that returns string.");
                return;
            }

            // テキスト設定
            if (!useHTMLEncounterDefine) {
                encounterElem.innerText = parseActFormat(elementText, data.Encounter);
            } else {
                encounterElem.innerHTML = parseActFormat(elementText, data.Encounter);
            }
        }

        // ヘッダを更新する
        function updateCombatantListHeader() {
            var table = document.getElementById('combatantTable');
            var tableHeader = document.createElement("thead");
            tableHeader.id = "combatantTableHeader";
            var headerRow = tableHeader.insertRow();

            for (var i = 0; i < headerDefine.length; i++) {
                var cell = document.createElement("th");
                // テキスト設定
                if (typeof headerDefine[i].text !== 'undefined') {
                    cell.innerText = headerDefine[i].text;
                } else if (typeof headerDefine[i].html !== 'undefined') {
                    cell.innerHTML = headerDefine[i].html;
                }
                // 幅設定
                cell.style.width = headerDefine[i].width;
                cell.style.maxWidth = headerDefine[i].width;
                // 横結合数設定
                if (typeof headerDefine[i].span !== 'undefined') {
                    cell.colSpan = headerDefine[i].span;
                }
                // 行揃え設定
                if (typeof headerDefine[i].align !== 'undefined') {
                    cell.style["textAlign"] = headerDefine[i].align;
                }
                headerRow.appendChild(cell);
            }

            table.tHead = tableHeader;
        }

        // プレイヤーリストを更新する
        function updateCombatantList(data) {
            // 要素取得＆作成
            var table = document.getElementById('combatantTable');
            var oldTableBody = table.tBodies.namedItem('combatantTableBody');
            var newTableBody = document.createElement("tbody");
            newTableBody.id = "combatantTableBody";

            // tbody の内容を作成
            var combatantIndex = 0;
            for (var combatantName in data.Combatant) {
                var combatant = data.Combatant[combatantName];
                var tableRow = newTableBody.insertRow(newTableBody.rows.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < bodyDefine.length; i++)
                {
                    var cell = tableRow.insertCell(i);
                    // テキスト設定
                    if (typeof bodyDefine[i].text !== 'undefined') {
                        var cellText;
                        if (typeof bodyDefine[i].text === 'function') {
                            cellText = bodyDefine[i].text(combatant, combatantIndex);
                        } else {
                            cellText = parseActFormat(bodyDefine[i].text, combatant);
                        }
                        cell.innerText = cellText;
                    } else if (typeof bodyDefine[i].html !== 'undefined') {
                        var cellHTML;
                        if (typeof bodyDefine[i].html === 'function') {
                            cellHTML = bodyDefine[i].html(combatant, combatantIndex);
                        } else {
                            cellHTML = parseActFormat(bodyDefine[i].html, combatant);
                        }
                        cell.innerHTML = cellHTML;
                    }
                    // 幅設定
                    cell.style.width = bodyDefine[i].width;
                    cell.style.maxWidth = bodyDefine[i].width;
                    // 行構え設定
                    if (typeof(bodyDefine[i].align) !== 'undefined') {
                        cell.style.textAlign = bodyDefine[i].align;
                    }
                    // エフェクト実行
                    if (typeof bodyDefine[i].effect === 'function') {
                        bodyDefine[i].effect(cell, combatant, combatantIndex);
                    }
                }
                combatantIndex++;
            }

            // tbody が既に存在していたら置換、そうでないならテーブルに追加
            if (oldTableBody != void(0)) {
                table.replaceChild(newTableBody, oldTableBody);
            }
            else {
                table.appendChild(newTableBody);
            }
        }

        // Miniparse フォーマット文字列を解析し、表示文字列を取得する
        function parseActFormat(str, dictionary)
        {
            var result = "";

            var currentIndex = 0;
            do {
                var openBraceIndex = str.indexOf('{', currentIndex);
                if (openBraceIndex < 0) {
                    result += str.slice(currentIndex);
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    result += str.slice(currentIndex, openBraceIndex);
                    var closeBraceIndex = str.indexOf('}', openBraceIndex);
                    if (closeBraceIndex < 0) {
                        // parse error!
                        console.log("parseActFormat: Parse error: missing close-brace for " + openBraceIndex.toString() + ".");
                        return "ERROR";
                    }
                    else {
                        var tag = str.slice(openBraceIndex + 1, closeBraceIndex);
                        if (typeof dictionary[tag] !== 'undefined') {
                            result += dictionary[tag];
                        } else {
                            console.log("parseActFormat: Unknown tag: " + tag);
                            result += "ERROR";
                        }
                        currentIndex = closeBraceIndex + 1;
                    }
                }
            } while (currentIndex < str.length);

            return result;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="encounter">
        No data to show.
        <!-- ここにエンカウント情報が入る -->
    </div>

    <table id="combatantTable">
        <!-- ここにヘッダが入る -->
        <!-- ここに各キャラの情報が入る -->
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is a bit unclear what you're asking, I can't see how the code has anything to do with decimal or integers.

Comment: @Vitim.us I have updated the post with more information.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided doesn't include any data, just the rendering algorithm. Without knowing what the data looks like, I can only guess based on what I can assume from the code. I can read the comments tho.

```js
function parseActFormat(str, dictionary)
        {
            var result = "";

            var currentIndex = 0;
            do {
                var openBraceIndex = str.indexOf('{', currentIndex);
                if (openBraceIndex < 0) {
                    result += str.slice(currentIndex);
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    result += str.slice(currentIndex, openBraceIndex);
                    var closeBraceIndex = str.indexOf('}', openBraceIndex);
                    if (closeBraceIndex < 0) {
                        // parse error!
(...)
```

Just scanning this, it looks like a naive templating engine, for replacing I guess that part `text: "{encdps}"`

...

Also

```js
var cell = tableRow.insertCell(i);
                    // テキスト設定
                    if (typeof bodyDefine[i].text !== 'undefined') {
                        var cellText;
                        if (typeof bodyDefine[i].text === 'function') {
                            cellText = bodyDefine[i].text(combatant, combatantIndex);
                        } else {
                            cellText = parseActFormat(bodyDefine[i].text, combatant);
                        }
                        cell.innerText = cellText;
```

From that part it seems that you can define the text as a **function** instead of a string, so try this:

```js
{ text: function(combatant){ return Number(String(combatant.encdps)).toFixed(0); }, width: "20%", align: "right" },
```